# unable to run XServer (wierdx) on browser

Tags: java, applet, x11, xserver, x11-forwarding

I am trying to use X Server on Browser hence i initially tried weirdx-1.0.32.jar .
by running the same with java -jar command ,and i faced success by manipulating DISPLAY env variable (2.png).

But when i tried to run the applet in browser(on apache server) , i was not able to open my application on XServer (i.e. browser) (1.png),

- am i missing some configuration ?
- is there any other alternative for weirdx ?

[image]

[image]